# How to deal with canvas using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, canvas

I try to test this website  https://classpad.net/classpad/use-as-guest using Selenium. I do not know how to make the form to select visible. Please see pictures below for more detail.

**[Before I click on blank area]**

[image]

**[After I click]**

[image]

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DriverScript {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebElement element;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.navigate().to("http://34.201.210.27/classpad");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/a[2]")).click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("scratchpaper-detail")));

        JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("$('.scratchpaper-detail .stickyContainer .inputForm').show()");


        String element = driver.getTitle();

        System.out.println(element);

    }


}
```